# Cannot Connect to Memorystore from Compute Engine Vm Instance (GCP)

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a memorystore running in region A and I have a compute engine VM running in region B.
AND I am not able to connect to memorystore(A) from my VM(B).

I am trying the connection via just telnet the port of memorystore i.e 6379 from my VM in region B.

[I have read the Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-gce) and find out that you can only connect to your Redis instance from Compute Engine VM instances that are in the same region and use the same VPC network as your instance.

But why is it so?. Can't there a way to connect to memorystore from VM running in multiple regions

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can only connect to a **Cloud Memorystore** for Redis instance from resources in the same [region](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/regions) as your instance. The fact that the connections should come from the same region as the resource is a requirement of Memorystore.

However, there is an open **feature request** to enable connections from different regions. Even though there is no specific timelines provided, you can track its status [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/111260473).

Comment: is there any way we can enable authentication and authorization for memorystore. If yes, could you please share the reference link.